# How to place few figures after references/bibliography in latex

Tags: pdftex, positioning, figure-placement

I am planning to submit a paper to a conference, which has a requirement that some figures should be after the references/bibliography. Is it possible to do this in LaTeX?

PS: I am not saying LaTeX puts figures in references and I want to move them before - I know there are many questions and solutions for that. I am asking the reverse thing.

Comment: Have you tried positioning the figure after the references section and use `[h]`?

Comment: Thanks! That worked :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Below is a sample paper, which appends two figures at the end of it.

Firstly, place `figure` environments after the command that creates the bibliography (in the code `\printbibliographgy` from `biblatex`).

Secondly, use optional argument `[p]` or `[tbh]`. The latter is usual and causes figures to appear in text, here right after the bibliography as long as there is enough space. On the other hand, `[p]` will cause figures to appear on a separate *float page* meaning a page break will be added before regardless of how much space is left after the bibliography.

`filecontents` creates a file required by `biblatex`. `\jobname` expands to a name of the main document e.g. `output` if the main file is `output.tex`. Hence `\jobname.bib` will become `output.bib`.

As a side note, you might want to try to gather images in one `figure` environment and control a gap between them; change `\bigskip` to `\vspace{...}` if you prefer a different gap, e.g. `\vspace{1cm}`.

```latex
\begin{figure}[p]
  \centering
  \includegraphics[scale=0.65]{example-image-a}
  \caption{Image A}\label{fig:A}

  \bigskip

  \includegraphics[scale=0.65]{example-image-a}
  \caption{Image B}\label{fig:B}
\end{figure}
```

The main code:

```latex
\begin{filecontents}[overwrite]{\jobname.bib}
@article{frie2002,
    author  = {Jonathan Friedland},
    title   = {Across the Divide},
    journal = {Guardian}, 
    pages   = {10-11},
    date    = {2002-01-15},
    entrysubtype = {newspaper},
    url     = {https://www.theguardian.com/uk},
    urldate = {2016-09-16},
}
@book{ref:murphy2012,
  title = {Machine Learning: A Probabilistic Perspective},
  author = {Murphy, Kevin P.},
  date = {2012},
  series = {Adaptive {{Computation}} and {{Machine Learning}} Series},
  publisher = {{The MIT Press}},
  abstract = {A comprehensive introduction to machine learning that uses probabilistic models and inference as a unifying approach.},
  isbn = {978-0-262-01802-9},
  url = {http://www.example.url.address},
  file = {/home/ziko/Documents/research/papers/pdfs/Murphy/2012/murphy_2012_machine learning.pdf}
}
@www{GoogleWWW,
  title        = {Google website},
  author       = {Google},
  url = {https://www.google.com},
  year         = 2022,
  note         = {Accessed:2022-07-23},
}
@online{CitekeyMiscAudio,
  title        = {Audio: The 'Other' Red Planet},
  author       = {NASA},
  url = {https://www.nasa.gov/nh/pluto-the-other-red-planet},
  year         = 2015,
  note         = {Accessed: 2018-12-06},
}
@online{CitekeyMiscVideo,
  title        = {Video: The 'Other' Red Planet},
  author       = {NASA},
  url = {https://www.nasa.gov/nh/pluto-the-other-red-planet},
  year         = 2015,
  note         = {Accessed: 2018-12-06},
}
\end{filecontents}
%%% 
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{blindtext}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{biblatex}

\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}
\title{\bfseries The Title}
\author{Xxxxxx Yyyyyyy}
\date{}


\begin{document}
\maketitle
\blindmathpaper\Blinddocument
\nocite{*}
\printbibliography

\begin{figure}[p]
  \centering
  \includegraphics[scale=0.65]{example-image-a}
  \caption{Image A}\label{fig:A}
\end{figure}
  
\begin{figure}[p]
  \centering
  \includegraphics[scale=0.65]{example-image-b}
  \caption{Image B}\label{fig:B}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you, that worked! Simply placing figures after bibliography! Embarrassing to miss such a simple thing. Plus, I had a separate `.bib` file, so I didn't need the `filecontents` and `\jobname` part - hopefully, it will help someone else. However, I had a question regarding your suggestion to use a single figure environment. Is that better than using different figure environments for different figures? Is it a commonly adopted convention?

Comment: `filecontents` is in the code only to make demonstrating code self-contained and let it work for everyone, with/without `*.bib` file.

Comment: There are no conventions, at least none I know of. It is your choice. With one `figure` env., your images stack vertically without space and you need to take care of vertical spacing. However, you could also reduce their size and distribute them horizontally if you'd prefer. With separate `figure` envs., the decision is left to LaTeX, roughly speaking.